# How can discord bot get thumbnail of the game that user is playing at the moment?

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to write simple Discord Bot using discord.js (nodejs app) that will track users' in-game time. I also want to send embedded message to the channels once the user stops playing game.

I am using "presenceUpdate" event for all this logic, and have been able to acquire name of the game and also send a message to a chat. However I want also to display game's thumbnail in the message, but unfortunately I have no clue how to find this thumbnail.

Here's the snippet of code I use to detect finished game, get playing time and send message to chat.

```
const user = newPresence.user;
const activities = activityDiff(oldPresnece, newPresence);

activities.forEach(activity => {
    const playTime = getPlayTime(activity);
    newPresence.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.isText()).each(channel => {
        channel.send("Mesasge...")
    })
})
```

Inside Activity object I find attribute called applicationId that has some value, but I do not know how to use it. I have seen other bots showing thumbnails of the games in their chat messages, and it is unlikely that they have their own database of thumbnails and populate it with (applicationId, thumbnail) pairs. It's so much work when there is so much games out there. There must be some common database for these thumbnails...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`RichPresenceAssets.smallImageURL()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichPresenceAssets?scrollTo=smallImageURL). This is how to implement it:

```js
member.presence.activities[0].assets.smallImageURL()
```

Comment: I am sorry but "assets" attribute is NULL. I am testing with No Man Sky game from steam.

Comment: I have also tried CS:GO and Cyberpunk games from steam, also that "assets" attribute is null.